# Ajax php update mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I want to update mysql records using ajax and php. i tested it works fine on local sever always but sometimes give error on live server please guide...
What is wrong in this code sometimes work fine sometime gives error 505 bad getway or sometime 404 on live server........

```
Ajax function 
//=================== Save Data ============================
function savegData()
{
    var ProjectId='<?php echo $ProjectId;?>';
    var expertId='<?php echo $expertId;?>';
    $("#noverlay").fadeIn(100);
    alertify.success("Saving...");
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'../save.php',
        data:{Projectid:ProjectId,expertid:expertId,
                A1a1marks:$("#intellect1").val(),
                A1a2marks:$("#intellect2").val(),
                A1bmarks:$("#intellect3").val(),
                A1cmarks:$("#intellect4").val(),
                A1totalmarks:$("#sumIntellect").text(),
                A1comments:$("#commentIntellect").val(),
                A2amarks:$("#significance1").val(),
                A2bmarks:$("#significance2").val(),
                A2cmarks:$("#significance3").val(),
                A2dmarks:$("#significance4").val(),
                A2emarks:$("#significance5").val(),
                A2totalmarks:$("#sumSignificance").text(),
                A2comments:$("#commentSignificance").val(),
                A3amarks:$("#approach1").val(),
                A3bmarks:$("#approach2").val(),
                A3cmarks:$("#approach3").val(),
                A3dmarks:$("#approach4").val(),
                A3emarks:$("#approach5").val(),
                A3totalmarks:$("#sumApproach").text(),
                A3comments:$("#commentApproach").val(),
                B1amarks:$("#economic1").val(),
                B1bmarks:$("#economic2").val(),
                B1cmarks:$("#economic3").val(),
                B1dmarks:$("#economic4").val(),
                B1emarks:$("#economic5").val(),
                B1totalmarks:$("#sumEconomic").text(),
                B1comments:$("#commentEconomic").val(),
                B2amarks:$("#research1").val(),
                B2bmarks:$("#research2").val(),
                B2totalmarks:$("#sumResearch").text(),
                B2comments:$("#commentResearch").val(),
                B3amarks:$("#education1").val(),
                B3bmarks:$("#education2").val(),
                B3cmarks:$("#education3").val(),
                B3dmarks:$("#education4").val(),
                B3emarks:$("#education5").val(),
                B3totalmarks:$("#sumEducation").text(),
                B3comments:$("#commentEducation").val(),
                B4amarks:$("#collaboration1").val(),
                B4bmarks:$("#collaboration2").val(),
                B4cmarks:$("#collaboration3").val(),
                B4dmarks:$("#collaboration4").val(),
                B4emarks:$("#collaboration5").val(),
                B4fmarks:$("#collaboration6").val(),
                B4gmarks:$("#collaboration7").val(),
                B4hmarks:$("#collaboration8").val(),
                B4imarks:$("#collaboration9").val(),
                B4totalmarks:$("#sumCollaboration").text(),
                B4comments:$("#commentCollaboration").val(),
                Camarks:$("#infrastructure1").val(),
                Cbmarks:$("#infrastructure2").val(),
                Ccmarks:$("#infrastructure3").val(),
                Cdmarks:$("#infrastructure4").val(),
                Cemarks:$("#infrastructure5").val(),
                Ctotalmarks:$("#sumInfrastructure").text(),
                Ccomments:$("#commentInfrastructure").val(),
                Damarks:$("#reasonability1").val(),
                Dbmarks:$("#reasonability2").val(),
                Dc1marks:$("#reasonability3").val(),
                Dc2marks:$("#reasonability4").val(),
                Ddmarks:$("#reasonability5").val(),
                Dtotalmarks:$("#sumReasonability").text(),
                Dcomments:$("#commentReasonability").val(),
                totalmarks:GrandTotal,
                totalpercentage:percentage,

                piRecommended:$('#budgetRecommended1').val(),
                copiRecommended:$('#budgetRecommended2').val(),
                phd_studentRecommended:$('#budgetRecommended3').val(),
                ms_studentRecommended:$('#budgetRecommended4').val(),
                permanentEquipmentRecommended:$('#budgetRecommended5').val(),
                expendableSuppliesRecommended:$('#budgetRecommended6').val(),
                travelRecommended:$('#budgetRecommended7').val() ,

                LDIetcRecommended:$('#budgetRecommended8').val(),
                stationaryRecommended:$('#budgetRecommended9').val(),

                miscellaneousRecommended:$("#budgetRecommended10").val(),
                //otherRecommended:$('#budgetRecommended11').val() ,
                secretariatRecommended:$("#budgetRecommended11").val() ,

                indirectCostRecommended :$("#budgetRecommended12").val() ,
                totalRecommended:$('#totalRecommend').text(),

                piComments:$('#budgetReason1').val(),
                copiComments:$('#budgetReason2').val(),
                phd_studentComments:$('#budgetReason3').val(),
                ms_studentComments:$('#budgetReason4').val(),
                permanentEquipmentComments:$('#budgetReason5').val(),
                expendableSuppliesComments:$('#budgetReason6').val(),
                travelComments:$('#budgetReason7').val(),
                LDIetcComments:$('#budgetReason8').val(),
                stationaryComments:$('#budgetReason9').val() ,
                miscellaneousComments:$("#budgetReason10").val() ,
                secretariatComments:$("#budgetReason11").val() ,
                //Comments:$('#budgetReason11').val() ,
                indirectCostComments:$('#budgetReason12').val() ,
                decision:previousChecked
            },
              async:false,
        success:function(responce){
                    setTimeout(function()
                        {
                         alertify.success(responce);
                            $("#noverlay").fadeOut(200);
                         window.location='reviewReport.php?project_id='+ProjectId+'&expertid='+expertId;
                        },3000);
        },
       error: function (error) {
           $("#noverlay").fadeOut(200);
            console.log(error);
        },
    }); 

}
```

Comment: Please describe the error, and what you expect to happen, what does not happen, and pinpoint where in that code the problem occurs.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: As a side note, never use: `async:false,` in today's jquery usage.

Comment: mostly i don't use asyn:flase but now i just  tried it ....

Comment: If it works on local server but not live server, the problem may be here : `url:'../save.php'`, are you sure the path is the good?

Comment: Use your browser console to see *where* the request is going. Ie. what is the absolute URI? Is it right? `../save.php` is very suspicious.

Comment: Yah i am sure it is correct beacuse it works most of time .... but in sometimes it gives  505 bad getway error in console  and sometimes gives 404 i can't understand why it is doing this ...